# Could not broadcast input array from shape (164,14) into shape (164)

Tags: python, opencv

Could not broadcast input array from shape (164,14) into shape (164) at keypoints_1. I think the shape is difference because of sift.detectAndCompute() method on line 6?

```
for f in files:
    rawimg1 = cv2.imread(f)
    myimg1 = cv2.cvtColor(rawimg1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    img1 = np.array(myimg1)
    # img1.ravel()
    yourimg1 = sift.detectAndCompute(myimg1,None)
    keypoints_1 = np.array(yourimg1)
    # keypoints_1.ravel()
    descriptors_1 = np.array(yourimg1)
    # descriptors_1.ravel()
path = '/images/627'
```

Comment: can you print the shape in each steps?

Comment: i can't print the shape in line 6. for this line:     
```yourimg1 = sift.detectAndCompute(myimg1,None)```

Comment: but, please at least add for the part you can! Without any idea about your data shapes it's hard to get an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try as below code.

```
for f in files:
  rawimg1 = cv2.imread(f)
  gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

  # img1.ravel()
  keypoints_1, descriptors_1  = sift.detectAndCompute(gray ,None)
path = '/images/627'
```